# Символы внутри xml элемента

Tags: php, laravel, xml, soap, символы

Всех приветствую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю следующую ошибку.
Причина ошибки заключаются в следующем :
В моей базе содержатся данные, которые я преобразовываю в xml файл. Внутри столбца description лежат записи формата text содержащие символы которые не закодировались.
[?] и т.д.

```
$description = $dom->createElement("description",htmlentities($item[$i]->description));
```

Если я их не буду кодировать с помощью htmlentities, то у меня вылезает ошибка из за неверных символов.

**Мой XML**

```
<description>
   sfdkjsfdnkjfdsnkjdfnksdjnfksjdfn
   fsd&raquo;
   &bull; item1
   &bull; item2
   &bull; item3
   &bull; item4
</description>
```

Подскажите есть ли подобный метод htmlentities для xml записей. Есть идея вырезать из строки символы и при формировании обратно добавлять. Но это получается совсем кустарный метод.

Comment: а зачем в xml что-то кодировать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот такие вот данные )

Comment: ....Такие - какие?

Answer (score 0):

Эти сущности есть только в HTML, в XML их нет, поэтому либо надо их объявить, примерно так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE myname  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
    <!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
    <!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
    <!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
    <!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
    <!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
    <!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;">
    <!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
    <!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
    <!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<data>
...
</data>
```

Либо заменить на сущности которые понимает XML
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html